# How to write VBA in Access to run change queries

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a bunch of update and change queries that I want to run all at once in VBA. I am brand new to VBA so what do I need to write in a module in order to run it in the VBA window? All I could find was the following:

`CurrentDb.Execute "Query1"
 CurrentDb.Execute "Query2"`

What else needs to be added at the beginning and the end to get this to run?

Comment: Not sure what your question is as it sounds very basic. You may need to learn or re-learn VBA (sub, function, etc.) or how to integrate code in Access.

Comment: You need to put it in some procedure. Could be a button Click event. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Access-programming-25EDAEFE-E917-4608-8BA0-DAB7C75CBE0C?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Have you considered a macro instead?

Comment: @DonGeorge yes, that is what I did, I needed a fuction start and end then I needed to create a macro to call the procedure. I was able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

This is what needs to be added:

```
 `Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit
 Function Queries()
 CurrentDb.Execute "Query1"
 CurrentDb.Execute "Query2"
 End Function
`
```